# Excluding variables from summary of lm() with Fixed Effects

Tags: r, output, summary

Suppose I estimate the below OLS model with fixed effects and summarize it as follows:

```
m <- lm(x ~ y + factor(z)) 
summary(m)
```

If z is sufficiently large, the summarized output is quite lengthy because it displays information for each elements of z as a coefficient. Is there a way to consolidate this output so that I don't have a coefficient for each element of z but instead simply see "FE: Yes" or simply excluding the FE from the table? I am trying to find a generalized solution.

Comment: Please provide some sample data. Whats `x`, `y` and `z`?

Comment: What do you mean by "FE: yes"? Do you mean that you would like to see only the statistically significant estimates in the output? Only effects with a certain absolute magnitude? Only effects with a certain effect size? Personally, I think that automatizing statistical decision-making is *very* ill-advised...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one possible interpretation of your request:

`summary(m)$coefficients[ !grepl("z", names(coef(m)) ) , ,drop=FALSE] 
 # tested only on example from ?lm`

If it's not what you what, then please make both a more complete description, as well as a test case with desired output.

Answer (score 2):

Use stargazer package to print the model summary, and use the omit option to depress the factor names in the output. To include a line saying fixed effects = true, you could use the option additional.lines to include that one the bottom of your table. Stargazer can output type as html, text or latex.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you really want to simplify the levels in z.

```
FE = z == "FE"
lm(x ~ y + factor(FE))
```